# what is the reason for the result in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var re1=new RegExp("","g");
var str1="a";
console.log(str1.match(re1));

var re2=new RegExp("","g");
var str2="a";
console.log(re2.exec(str2));
console.log(re2.exec(str2));
```

why the first will capture two empty string,and the second can only contain one empty string?

Comment: @Vache: `match` will return all results, but `exec` will only ever return one. I think your edit invalidates the question.

Comment: @icktoofay Yeah I completely misunderstood what was meant in the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between javascripts regex exec() function and string match() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-javascripts-regex-exec-function-and-string-matc)

Comment: @Daniel: Not quite. You should usually be able to replace a call to `match` with an `exec` loop; in this case, however, they yield different results, and that's what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: it doesn’t.

```
js> var re1 = new RegExp("", "g");
js> var str1 = "a";
js> str1.match(re1)
["", ""]
js> var re2 = new RegExp("", "g");
js> var str2 = "a";
js> re2.exec(str2)
[""]
js> re2.exec(str2)
[""]
```

Each of these `[""]`s is a result, as `exec` is meant to be called in a loop and retrieve both all matches *and* all groups, as in:

```
var pairs = /(.).*?\1/g;
var input = "._.  ^.^ -__-";
var match;

while (match = pairs.exec(input)) { // exec() returns null on /g regexes when there are no more matches
    console.log(match);
}
```

A more interesting question might be why `re2.lastIndex` doesn’t change after matching, so you can get the same match forever and it’ll never be `null`. Well, that’s just because it advances by the length of the match for each match, and here the length is zero.

Comment: u can continue to run the re2.exec(str2) and will get the same result,but re2.lastIndex's result never changed,why?   var re2=new RegExp("","g");
    var str2="a";
    console.log(re2.exec(str2),re2.lastIndex);
    console.log(re2.exec(str2),re2.lastIndex);
    console.log(re2.exec(str2),re2.lastIndex);

Comment: .nice answer and nice person..haha