# jquery regex just finds first occurrence

Tags: jquery, regex

im trying to find specific class patterns for a script.
but my regex call is failing to find all occurrences.
Instead it just returns the first one.

```
string = "col-xs-1 col-md-middle col-lg-middle"
s = /col(?:-(..)-|-)(?:middle|top|bottom)/g.exec(string);
console.log(s)

output -> ["col-md-middle", "md"]
```

does anyone know what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.match` function. `exec` with a global regular expression is meant to be used in a loop, as it will still retrieve all matched subexpressions.

```
> str.match(/col(?:-(..)-|-)(?:middle|top|bottom)/g)
[ 'col-md-middle', 'col-lg-middle' ]
```

If you want to get the match aswell as captures then use the below.

```
> var re = /col(?:-(..)-|-)(?:middle|top|bottom)/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> var a = [];
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... a.push(m[0])
... a.push(m[1])
... }
4
> a
[ 'col-md-middle',
  'md',
  'col-lg-middle',
  'lg' ]
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun)

Comment: can you might tell my why the original code is not working the way it should?

Comment: `re.exec` function alone return only the first match. But when it is used inside a loop, it would print all the matches, since the loop iterates until no match is found.

Comment: well logical, might be because of speed reasons, still confusing why they didnt made it gloval. anyway thx

Answer (score 0):

```
    var t = this
        s = t.attr('class').match(/(col(-(..)-|-)(middle|top|bottom))/g).join(' ').split('-');
    $(s).each(function(k,v){
        if (k%2!==0) {
           // here i get the string after col-
        }
    });
```

here is my solution,
a bit smaller and i like to avoid whiles, they just love to infinity loop themselves