# Javascript regex to extract variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in Javascript that contains variables with the format `${var-name}`. For example:

```
'This is a string with ${var1} and ${var2}'
```

I need to get these variables in an array: `['var1','var2']`.

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: this gives `[ "${var1}", "${var2}" ]`

Comment: Do you need array of variables or array of names of variables, mentioned in the string?

Comment: see my example, array of variable names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
/\$\{(\w+?)\}/
```

Running example, many thanks to @RGraham :

```
var regex = new RegExp(/\$\{(\w+?)\}/g),
    text = "This is a string with ${var1} and ${var2} and {var3}",
    result,
    out = [];
while(result = regex.exec(text)) {
    out.push(result[1]);
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: @RGraham: You're right, I'm not used to regex javascript.

Comment: You were close enough: If you want to use variables in a Regex, you have the use the `RegExp` objects with quotes:
`var regex = new RegExp("\\$\\{(\\w+?)\\}", "g")`

Comment: If you're not leveraging the [benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun) of `exec()`, then stick to String's `match()` as it's a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/nO4sU8/5) - `\${([^\s}]+)(?=})` - should work.

Explanation:

- `\${` - Match literal `${`
- `([^\s}]+)` - A capture group that will match 1 or more character that are not whitespace or literal `}`.
- `(?=})` - A positive look-ahead that will check if we finally matched a literal `}`.

Here is sample code:

```js
var re = /\${([^\s}]+)(?=})/g; 
var str = 'This is a string with ${var1} and ${var2} and {var3}';
var arr = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    arr.push(m[1]);
}

alert(arr);
```

Comment: Nice to see an explanation of Regex for a change! However, this doesn't take into account the `$` and will match `'This is a string with {var1}` too. Also anything that ends with a `}` like `'this is a test}`

Comment: @RGraham: I guess these cases are not expected. If they are, then it is really easy to fix by `\${([^\s}]+)(?=})`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'This is a string with ${var1} and ${var2}';

var re = /\$\{(\w+?)\}/g;
var arr = [];
var match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  arr.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I don't need to replace the variables, just to load them in an array

Comment: `\w+?` - can you explain why there is a `?` in here? What does that match?

Comment: `?` meas as less chars as possible.

Comment: But doesn't `\w+` ensure at least char?

Comment: @alsotang, when you post code to answer a question, you should explain what the OP did wrong and what you did to fix it.