# Javascript Confusing Regex Groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regular expression which works great on regexr.com , but does not work with Javascript.

Here is the link to regexr http://regexr.com/3b780

Below is my Javascript attempt

```
      var expression="--user=foo:This is description"
      var regexExp = new RegExp("(?:=)(.[^:]+)|(?::)(.[^=]+)|(.[^=^:]+)","g");
      console.log(regexExp.exec(expression))
```

Which returns

```
[ '--user',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  '--user',
  index: 0,
  input: '--user=foo:This is description' 
]
```

### Expected Output

```
[ '--user',
  'foo',
  'This is description',
  '--user',
  index: 0,
  input: '--user=foo:This is description' 
]
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Are you sure you want to capture three groups as three different matches? (It’s why the spacing is unusual on your regexr output.)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegExp#exec` with a global regular expression [needs to be called multiple times to get all matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun/9214797#9214797). You can get closer with `String#match` (use a regular expression literal, by the way):

```
var expression = "--user=foo:This is description";
var re = /(?:=)(.[^:]+)|(?::)(.[^=]+)|(.[^=^:]+)/g;
console.log(expression.match(re));
```

which results in:

```
Array [ "--user", "=foo", ":This is description" ]
```

However, that’s a very unusual regular expression. The non-capturing groups are useless, the capturing groups are never part of the same match, and `[^=^:]` probably doesn’t have the intended effect. Maybe something like this, instead?

```
var re = /(--.+?)=(.+?):(.+)/;
var expression = "--user=foo:This is description";
console.log(re.exec(expression));
```

resulting in:

```
Array [ "--user=foo:This is description", "--user", "foo", "This is description" ]
```

Comment: Okay make sense , if it has multiple groups , then we need to re execute multiple times.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the flow of `/(--.+?)=(.+?):(.+)/`

Comment: (--.+?) Get anything starting with --  , and capture it in a group until = and same goes on for all other groups

Comment: Actually dot(.) is used for getting any single character match only na ji....here what is the use of `.+?`

Comment: ? is for 0 or 1 , + is for 1 or more , we can also use * instead of +? , which means 0 or more

Comment: @papsk: `?` after a quantifier like `+` indicates a non-greedy match. It will match as few characters as possible. For example, `(a+?)(a+)` will capture `a` and `aa` in `aaa`, and `(a+)(a+)` will capture `aa` and `a`.

Comment: @minitech so will `(.+?):(.+)` capture `.`?