# Get first occurrence of string between two string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

i need to find the first occurrence of string between two string in Javascript, this is an example of my string:

```
"$$ hi my name is Mark $$"
```

i want get the text between the $$ how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following `regex`

```js
 var myStr = "$$ hi my name is Mark $$ And his name is John $$";
 var matches = myStr.match(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/);
 var str = matches && matches.length ? matches[1] : '';

 alert(str);
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiter of `regex`
2. `\$`: Matches `$` literal(Need to escape using `\`)
3. `()`: Capturing group
4. `.*?`: Matches any string

Comment: what is the difference between match and exec that use Magus in his answer?

Comment: @Piero http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun `exec with a global regular expression is meant to be used in a loop, as it will still retrieve all matched subexpressions.String.match does this for you and discards the subexpressions' results.`

Comment: i have notice that if the myStr doesn't contains the $$ delimiters give me an error 'null is not an object evaluating ...' how i can fix it?

Comment: now give me this error: 'null is not an object evaluating 'matches.length'

Comment: How to get the last occurrence ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression :

```
var mys = /\$\$(.*)\$\$/.exec('$$ hi my name is Mark $$')[1]
```

Comment: Why you use `"` inside the `string`, not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions.
As you only want the first match make sure to use non greedy.

```js
var yourVariable = "$$ hi my name is Mark $$ more stuff $$";
var match = yourVariable.match(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/)[1];
alert(match);
```