# Use loop and find html element's values JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use vanilla js to loop through a string of html text and get its values. with **jQuery** I can do something like this

```
var str1="<div><h2>This is a heading1</h2><h2>This is a heading2</h2></div>";
$.each($(str1).find('h2'), function(index, value) {
/// console.log($(value).text());
});
```

using `$(str)` converts it to an `html` string as I understand it and we can then use `.text()` to get an element `(h2)`'s value. 
but I want to do this within my node app on the backend rather than on the client side, because it'd be more efficient (?) and also it'd just be nice to not rely on **jQuery**.

Some context, I'm working on a blogging app. I want a table of contents created into an object server side.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to a achieve?

Comment: Why would you be having DOM nodes on the server where there is no DOM?

Comment: Well jQuery should work at backend, but considering not relying on it you would probably have to use some set of regular expression to find each element tag or the easiest way parse it through some document parser you can check the npm site for such parsers

Comment: @ScottMarcus probably web scraping for example

Comment: Cheerio can do this, but afaik it doesn't allow some things such as class manipulation.

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: I've updated the post to add some more context

Comment: To put my 2cents in, I would advise against this behavior that you're trying to achieve server side.

While serverside rendering can work on some circumstances, offloading it to the client to handle is for most use cases a better approach, because as a server increases in usage from requests, if it has to build all the markup for your client -> for every client, it's going to have to do a lot more work.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way using `.innerHTML` but uses the built-in [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Here's the operations we'll need, the types they have, and a link to the documentation of that function

- Create an HTML element from a text
  `String -> HTMLElement` – provided by [set Element#innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- Get the text contents of an HTML element
  `HTMLElement -> String` – provided by [get Element#innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- Find nodes matching a query selector
  `(HTMLElement, String) -> NodeList` – provided by [Element#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
- Transform a list of nodes to a list of text
  `(NodeList, HTMLElement -> String) -> [String]` – provided by [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
// html2elem :: String -> HTMLElement
const html2elem = html =>
  {
    const elem = document.createElement ('div')
    elem.innerHTML = html
    return elem.childNodes[0]
  }

// findText :: (String, String) -> [String]
const findText = (html, selector) =>
  Array.from (html2elem(html).querySelectorAll(selector), e => e.textContent)

// str :: String  
const str =
  "<div><h1>MAIN HEADING</h1><h2>This is a heading1</h2><h2>This is a heading2</h2></div>";

console.log (findText (str, 'h2'))
// [
//   "This is a heading1",
//   "This is a heading2"
// ]
// :: [String]

console.log (findText (str, 'h1'))
// [
//   "MAIN HEADING"
// ]
// :: [String]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to parse HTML is to use the DOM.  But, if all you have is a string of HTML, according to this [Stackoverflow member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214797/701302)) you may create a "dummy" DOM element to which you'd add the string to be able to manipulate the DOM, as follows:

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = "<html><head><title>aTitle</title></head>
<body><div><h2>This is a heading1</h2><h2>This is a heading2</h2></div>
</body</html>";
```

Now you have a couple of ways to access the data using the DOM, as follows:

```js
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = "<html><head><title>aTitle</title></head><body><div><h2>This is a heading1</h2><h2>This is a heading2</h2></div></body</html>";
    
    // one way
    el.g = el.getElementsByTagName;
    var h2s = el.g("h2");
    for(var i = 0, max = h2s.length; i < max; i++){
        console.log(h2s[i].textContent);
        if (i == max -1) console.log("\n");
    }
    
    // and another
    var elementList = el.querySelectorAll("h2");
    for (i = 0, max = elementList.length; i < max; i++) {
        console.log(elementList[i].textContent);
    }
```

You may also use a regular expression, as follows:

```js
var str = '<div><h2>This is a heading1</h2><h2>This is a heading2</h2></div>';

var re = /<h2>([^<]*?)<\/h2>/g;
var match;
var m = [];
var i=0;
while ( match = re.exec(str) ) {
    m.push(match.pop());
}
console.log(m);
```

The regex consists of an opening H2 tag followed by not a "<",followed by a closing H2 tag. The "*?" take into account zero or multiple instances of which there is at least zero or one instance.

Per [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214797/701302) of Stackoverflow:

> exec with a global regular expression is meant to be used in a loop,
>   as it will still retrieve all matched subexpressions.

The critical part of the regex is the "g" flag  as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).  It allows  the exec() method to obtain multiple matches in a given string. In each loop iteration, **match** becomes an array containing one element.  As each element is popped off and pushed onto **m**, the array **m** ultimately contains all the captured text values.