# Regex check both side of match but not include in match string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want get match with checking both side expropriation of main match.

var str = `1234 word !!! 5678 another *** 000more)))` get `word` and `another`

```
console.log(str.match(/(?!\d+\s?)\w+(?=\s?\W+)/g))
>> (3) ["word", "another", "more"]
```

it check both side but not include in the main match sets.

**But in html it not working** [not working]

var str = `'<a href="url"></a><a href="url2"></a><a href="url3"></a>';` get `url`, `url2` and `url3`

```
console.log(str.match(/(?!href=")[^"]+?(?=")/g))
>> (6) ["<a href=", "url", "></a><a href=", "url2", "></a><a href=", "url3"]
```

I try to Negative lookarounds using **`(?!href=")`** and Positive lookarounds using **`(?=")`** to match only the value of its attribute  but it return more attributes.

**Is there any way to so like this here, Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do for your example data is capture what is between double quotes [`href="([^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/F2130B/1) in an captured group and loop through the result:

```js
var str = '<a href="url"></a><a href="url2"></a><a href="url3"></a>';
var pattern = /href="([^"]+)/g;
var match = pattern.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  match = pattern.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: It's need to make an process to get my result.

Comment: Is there any way to get my result with `match` function :)
I really locking for ans with `match` function

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun) will explain the use of exec instead of match. This regex is based on your provided string but the answer from @Niet the Dark Absol is better when you can use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

In other flavors of regex you could have used e.g. *positive lookbehind*
(`(?<=href="`), but unfortunately Javascript regex does not support
lookbehinds.

A reasonable solution is:

- Match `href="` as "ordinary" content, to be ignored.
- Match the attribute value as a capturing group (`(\w+)`),
  to be "consumed".
- Set the boundary of the above group with a *positive lookup"
  (`(?=")`), just as you did.

So the whole regex can be:

```
href="(\w+)(?=")
```

and read "your" value from group 1.

Comment: It's a shame JS doesn't have lookbehinds. They're useful... But anyway, if you're already only taking group 1, there's no real benefit to using a lookahead for the last `"`, just match it outside the group `.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't parse HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674)

Have you tried using the DOM parser that's right at your fingertips?

```js
var str = '<a href="url"></a><a href="url2"></a><a href="url3"></a>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str; // parsing magic!
var links = Array.from(div.getElementsByTagName("a"));
var urls = links.map(function(a) {return a.href;});
// above returns fully-resolved absolute URLs.
// for the literal attribute value, try a.getAttribute("href")
console.log(urls);
```