# Plain Javascript Split String UPPER from lower case

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to split a String which contains an Uppercase Part + a Lowercase Part in Javascript (ES5). The String always looks like "UPPERlower".

Here's what i currently use

```
"ABCabc".match(/^[A-Z]+/g).concat("ABCabc".match(/[a-z]+$/g)) //result is ["ABC", "abc"]
```

Is there a cleaner code to achieve this?

EDIT:
Ori Drori's answer and mplungjan's answer are both correct for my Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `|` to match either the uppercase or lowercase sequence:

```js
var result = "ABCabc".match(/[A-Z]+|[a-z]+/g)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works like a charm i think mplungjan's answer is a better solution (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @Frozzem - whatever makes you happy :)

Comment: This will fail on multiple words if there are for example abcABC in a sentence

Comment: The String always looks like "UPPERlower".

Comment: If so, then the match seems more direct (returns an array)

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring is the modern way

```js
const s="UPPERlower";
let [,upper, lower] =/([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)/g.exec(s);
console.log(upper,lower);
```

Looping - NOTE: [What is the difference between RegExp’s exec() function and String’s match() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun)

```js
const s = "UPPERlower UPlow 123 lowUP UPPlowe"; 
// Note:above will produce low UP using .match(/[A-Z]+|[a-z]+/g) instead of capturing
const re = /([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)/g;
while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  [, upper, lower] = match;
  console.log(upper, lower)
}
```

Older way:

```js
var parts=/([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)/g.exec("UPPERlower");
console.log(parts[1],parts[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, although i dont really understand what you achieve by using let [, upper, lower]? Are you creating an array like [null, value of first part of regex, value of second part of regex]?

Comment: I create vars and ignore the first element of the exec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Wow, i did not know that was a thing, gotta thank you for that :). But I give the correct answer to Ori Drori for being pure ES5 (i know const and let are easily replaced), for ES6 this definitvly seems like the right answer, so i added a comment to my question linking to this as ES6 answer

Comment: I added an example using more backwards compatible JS - my exec is not very different from .match

Comment: Hmm, so if i have a simple regex match is fine, but if i had a complex regex exec would be better? Or is there a real advantage you get with 1 over the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun#

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me understand more, of whats going on in the background :D.

Comment: I added a loop. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun