# RegExp selection in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace tokens in a file. There can be multiple tokens on a line and the delimeters are `&&`.

Example:

```
{
  "host": "&&main_service&&/&&auth_endpoint&&"
}
```

If you use the regex:

```
const delimiter = '&&';
const delimeterRegex = new RegExp(`${delimiter}.*${delimiter}`);
```

...the problem is that that doesn't match individually; it can match that whole string (so I get `["&&main_service&&/&&auth_endpoint&&"]` as a result, rather than getting `["&&main_service&&", "&&auth_endpoint&&"]`)

How do I get the two results separately, rather than together?

EDIT: Code I use to do the replace:

```
const findUnreplacedTokens = () => {
  console.log('Scanning for unreplaced tokens...');
  const errors = [];
  lines.forEach((ln, i) => {
    const tokens = delimeterRegex.exec(ln);
    if (tokens) {
      errors.push({
        tokens,
        line: i+1,
      });
    }
  });

  if (errors.length) {
    handleErrors(errors);
  } else {
    console.log('No rogue tokens found');
    console.log(logSpacing);
  }
};
```

Comment: ``${delimiter}.*?${delimiter}``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Regular expression into non-greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm afraid not, if it's non-greedy like that, then it only removes the first match, even if I add a 'g' flag to the delimeterRegex. :(

Comment: Put whole code in your question.

Comment: @revo Code is commercially sensitive.

Comment: Not that whole. The part that deals with replacement.

Comment: IF you go to https://regex101.com/ and have the test string as `&&main_service&&/&&auth_endpoint&&` and the regex as `&&.*?&&*` (the forward slashes and the 'g' flag are added automatically) then that matches. I think it's the end star that is missing.

Comment: No you don't need the star https://regex101.com/r/edZAq5/1

Comment: @revo Sorry, double checked. You're right on the star.

Comment: Is it solved now? If yes you may want to accept an answer.

Comment: @revo No. Not yet. I'll accept as soon as it is. ;) I've edited to give the execution code, as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const regex = /&&(.*?)&&/g;
const str = `&&main_service&&/&&auth_endpoint&&`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach(function(match, groupIndex) {
      if(match.indexOf("&&") !== -1) return;
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is correct. The problem I was having came in two parts: (1) The `?` to make it non-greedy (must go inside capture group); (2) MDN says that exec returns an array yet, that's not the whole story - exec acts more like an generator. You need to run the exec repeatedly to get matches. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214955/1775718 <-- helped too)

Answer (score 0):

With [^&] and `g`(global)

> const delimeterRegex = new RegExp(`${delimiter}[^&]*${delimiter}`, 'g');

Comment: That would mean that the regex would have to match at the start of the string and finish at the end, and that might not be the case.

Comment: That seems to match the delimeters in the middle. Try it at https://regex101.com/