# Matching and grouping the same part of a string twice using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

It's quite hard to explain this using words, so perhaps I can just show what I'm wanting.

Currently I have the following code:

```js
  const regex = /(\d?\s\+?\s\d)|(\d?\s\-?\s\d)/g
  const match = '1 + 2 - 7'.match(regex)
  console.log(match)
```

This returns two matches:

```
[ "1 + 2", " - 7" ]
```

Now, what I want to know, is it possible to create a regex pattern that can match the integer `2` twice and make it part of two results?

**Desired output**:

```
[ "1 + 2", "2 - 7" ]
```

Comment: You'll always have 3 numbers there ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes It could be any number of numbers, but for the purposes of this question I just want to know if it's possible to achieve my desired output using regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a capturing group in a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[+-]` to match either `+` or `-`

```
(?=(\d+ [+-] \d+))
```

**Pattern parts**

- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `(` Capture group 1

    - `\d+ [+-] \d+` Match 1+ digits, space, either  + or -, space and 1+ digits
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU5F1Q/1)

Note that `\s` will also match a newline.

```js
const regex = /(?=(\d+ [+-] \d+))/g;
const str = `1 + 2 - 7`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: @JossClassey If you don't use a while loop, you will only get the first result. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun) might be helpful about [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for the great answer :)